# How to clear apple expo:build cookies?

Tags: ios, expo

I'm trying to run expo build:ios however I get an accessForbidden error, but this is uncommon.  It gave me the option the first time to choice either provider 1 or provider 2 in this line:

```
› Provider [provider 1] ()
```

I wasn't sure which provider to choose, so I chose provider 2, when I should have chosen provider 1.  However, now i can't get the option to choose provider 1 as it auto loads provider 2 when building.  How can I clear this so I have the option for provider 1 again? Can i delete the session cookie path it has listed there?

```
› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … ID
› Restoring session /Users/name/.app-store/auth/ID@/cookie
✔ Select a Team › Team - Company/Organization ()
› Provider [provider] ()
✔ Logged in Local session

Network Timeout: 'AccessForbiddenError', 'Apple 403 detected - Access forbidden'. Retrying after 3 seconds (remaining: 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do this myself - for any others that come across this, yes you can safely delete the cookie file, you'll be prompted to log in and select your provider again next time you run expo/eas build.